# Does flatness ascend through a free ring map?

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness, free-modules

Suppose I have a composition of ring maps (rings commutative with identity)

$$R \xrightarrow{f} S \xrightarrow{g} T$$

where $f$ and $g$ are monomorphisms, $S$ is $R$-free, and $T$ is (faithfully) $R$-flat.

> Is it also true that $T$ is $S$-flat?

For example, if $R[[x]]$ is flat over $R$, is $R[[x]]$ flat over $R[x]$? What if we replace $R[[x]]$ by an overring of $R[x]$?

I know that faithfulness will not generally lift like this (if $T$ is a localization of $S$ it certainly won't) but it seems intuitive to me that flatness would ascend through a free ring extension.

Comment: Let $K$ be a field and let $R=K[x^2,y^2], S=K[x^2,xy,y^2], T=K[x,y]$ for a counter example.

Comment: Nice I will work through this now!

Comment: If you are able to address the polynomial/power series case in particular, I have asked about it here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816074/can-it-be-that-rx-is-flat-over-r-but-not-over-rx?noredirect=1&lq=1).  I appreciate your input.

Comment: I thought for this case, an answer is already given when $R$ is Noetherian. I do not know enough about non-Noetherian rings.

Comment: @Mohan Aha we are opposites in that respect. I am thinking right now only about non-noetherian rings, since in the Noetherian case the entire assumption about flatness of $R[[x]]$ over $R$ is eclipsed by the structure of $R$.

Comment: I think more than freeness of $S$ what you are looking for is something like $S$ being an étale extension.  If you knew $S$ was flat over $S \otimes_R S$, then flatness of $T$ would indeed ascend.  A classic example would be if $S$ is a localization of $R$.

Answer (score 1):

*Bourbaki's counter-example*:

Let $K$ be a field. Then $K[X]$ is free,  $K(X)$ is faithfully flat over $K$, but is certainly not faithfully flat over  $K[X]$ since this would imply $fK(X)\ne K(X)$ for any irreducible polynomial in $K[X]$.

Comment: The question only asks whether $K(X)$ is flat over $K[X]$, not faithfully flat.

Comment: But K(x) is trivially flat over K[x] so this is not a counter example.  Like I mentioned, faithfulness will usually not ascend. for example if S is a domain and T is a proper overring of S, T is never faithfully flat

Comment: I thought you only didn't want it to be faithfully flat over $S$. In this  case, take $T=K(X)\times K[X]/(f)$, $f$ irreducible: it has torsion over $K[X]$, so it can't be flat over it.

Comment: Yea actually I asked the question pretty poorly, I wasn't expecting this to be true in general but I was hoping someone more  knowledgeable than I might have an idea of an additional restriction to put on T so that it would be true.  Thank you for your thoughts and second counter example!