# Can it be that $R[[x]]$ is flat over $R$ but not over $R[x]$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, flatness

I have been trying to better understand the ascension of flatness.  After asking a poor question in general terms (see [Does flatness ascend through a free ring map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813013/does-flatness-ascend-through-a-free-ring-map?noredirect=1#comment5800401_2813013)), I realized that I do not understand even the fundamental polynomial/power series situation.

Namely, consider $$R \rightarrow R[X] \rightarrow R[[X]]$$

> If $R[[X]]$ is faithfully flat as an $R$-module, will flatness "ascend" to $R[[X]]$ as an $R[X]$-module?

The flatness of $R[[X]]$ over $R[X]$ [has been asked about on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173369/rx-flat-as-a-rx-module) but without answer or relevant comment.

I am guessing that flatness need not ascend since if we pick a countable coherent ring of large global dimension then $R[X]$ shouldn't (?) be coherent and I see no reason why it's completion should (?) be flat (but I have no confidence in this guess).  However it seems I do not know enough to produce (and verify) a counterexample.

I would really appreciate it if someone could shed light on this particular situation and / or share some thoughts on the topic of "**ascension of flatness**" generally, i.e. what features of the rings $R \rightarrow S \rightarrow T$ with $T$ faithfully flat as an $R$-module could cause $T$ to be faithfully flat as an $S$-module.

Comment: If $R$ is coherent, then $R[x]$ is coherent as well. I don't see how to show that $R[x] \rightarrow R[\![x]\!]$ is flat in that case though. Do you know such a statement?

Comment: @Louis Implicit in this post are two results about coherence of polynomial rings:

Comment: (1) The analog of the Hilbert basis theorem does not extend to coherence.  In particular Jean-Pierre Soublin produced a counterexample in 1970, available here https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869370900505.  (2) When $R$ is coherent and has low global dimension $R[X]$ is coherent.  This result is proven for gl. dim. $2$ in a paper of Greenberg and Vasconcelos from 1976 (https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-054-01/S0002-9939-1976-0417164-2/S0002-9939-1976-0417164-2.pdf).  I'm not sure if the result was later improved upon.

Comment: @BadamBaplan I thought Thm. 2.1. in the classical paper by chase would prove the converse, but I'm indeed wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ be a domain with fraction field $K$, denote by $D'$ the integral closure of $D$ and by $D''$ the complete integral closure (that is, the ring of elements $\frac{a}{b} \in K$ such that for some $d \in D, d(\frac{a}{b})^n \in D \ \forall n$)

> **Lemma:** If $D[[X]]$ is flat over $D[X]$, then $D'' = D'$.

**Proof**: Let $\frac{a}{b} \in K$ almost integral such that $d \frac{a^n}{b^n} \in D \ \forall n$.  Then let $G = d\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{aX}{b})^n \in D[[X]]$.  We have $(b-aX)G = bd$.  If $D[[X]]$ is flat then
$$\big((b-aX)\cap(bd)\big)D[[x]] = (b-aX)D[[X]]\cap(bd)D[[X]] = bdD[[X]]$$

Thus there exists $f \in (b-aX) \cap (bd)$ such that $fF = bd$.  Since $bd \mid f$, write $f = f' bd$ where $f'_0 = 1$, $f' \in D[X]$.  Since $b-aX \mid f$, write $g(b-aX) = f$.  Thus $\frac{g}{d}(1 - \frac{a}{b}X) = f'$ is a factorization of $f'$ in $K[X]$, and since the lowest coefficients are all $1$, it's well known that this is a factorization in $D'[X]$.  $\square$

So in order to ensure $R[[X]]$ is (faithfully) flat over $R$ but not flat over $R[X]$, a coherent domain in which $D''\not= D'$ will suffice.  This is easy, since valuation domains are coherent and are completely integrally closed precisely when they are rank 1.  We conclude:

> Any valuation domain $V$ of rank > 1 is such that $V[[x]]$ is (faithfully) flat over $V$ but $V[[X]]$ is not flat over $V[X]$.